# pandas query None values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns of different dtypes and I need to use  `pandas.query` to filter the columns.

Columns can include missing values: `NaN`, `None` and `NaT` and I need to display the rows that contain such values. Is there a way to do this in an expression passed to `pandas.query`? I am aware that it can be done using different methods but I need to know if it is doable through the `query`

For boolean columns I was able to use a workaround by stating:

```
df.query('col not in (True, False)')
```

but this won't work for other types of columns. Any help is appreciated including workarounds.

Comment: Can you use `np.isnan`?

Comment: @M.Massias the OP is asking for a query statement that is compatible with `df.query` method, the issue here is how to pass a statement that will work as desired using `numexpr`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`NaN` is not equal to itself, so you can simply test if a column is equal to itself to filter it.  This also seems to work for `None` although I'm not sure why, it may be getting cast to `NaN` at some point during the evaluation.

```
 df.query('col == col')
```

For datetimes, this works, but feels pretty hacky, there might be a better way.

```
df.query('col not in [@pd.NaT]')
```

Comment: Too bad that the second approach does not work for NaN and None! However the first works perfectly for me

Comment: For me, the second one work for None.